# Поиск bluetooth устройств Android

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

Поиск работает, но работает через раз, находит не все устройства, может вообще не запуститься поиск. Не всегда происходит событие `ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED`, не могу понять в чем дело. Помогите. Вот код

```
public class Find extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView myListDevices;
    private static final int ID_RESULT = 1;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> BTArrayAd;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList = new        
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean choice_pir = false;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    private  Parcelable[] uuidExtra = null;
    private LinkedHashSet<Parcelable> uuidsExtraFindDevices = new                  
    LinkedHashSet<>();
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;

    private final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            switch (action) {

                case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED: {

                    mProgressDlg.show();
                }
                break;

                // When discovery finds a device
                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND: {

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Устройство найдено");
                    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
                    mDeviceList.add(device);
                    BTArrayAd.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    //BTArrayAd.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                break;

                case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED: {

                    mProgressDlg.dismiss();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Поиск закончен");
                    // discovery has finished, give a call to fetchUuidsWithSdp on first device in list.
                    if (!mDeviceList.isEmpty()) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.remove(0);
                        boolean result = device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
                    }
                }
                break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID: {

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Вставка UUID");

                    // This is when we can be assured that fetchUuidsWithSdp has completed.
                    // So get the uuids and call fetchUuidsWithSdp on another device in list

                    BluetoothDevice deviceExtra = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    uuidExtra = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DeviceExtra address - " + deviceExtra.getAddress());
                    if (uuidExtra != null) {
                        for (Parcelable p : uuidExtra) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "uuidExtra - " + p);
                        }

                        uuidsExtraFindDevices.add(uuidExtra[uuidExtra.length - 1]);

                    } else {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "uuidExtra is still null");
                    }
                    if (!mDeviceList.isEmpty()) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.remove(0);
                        boolean result = device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
                    }
                }
                break;

            }
        }
    };





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find);

        myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        mProgressDlg = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDlg.setMessage("Scanning...");
        mProgressDlg.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDlg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }

        });


        myListDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listFind);
        BTArrayAd = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        BTArrayAd.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        myListDevices.setAdapter(BTArrayAd);

       // отмена сканирования

        BTArrayAd.clear();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);

        registerReceiver(bReceiver, filter);

          myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
          Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Поиск запущен");




        // Обработка события на клик по элементу списка
        myListDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                String address = String.valueOf(parent.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                int num = address.indexOf('\n');
                address = address.substring(num + 1);
                String [] data = new String[2];
                data[0] = address;
                Iterator<Parcelable> itr = uuidsExtraFindDevices.iterator();
                int count = 0;
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    if(count == position)
                        data[1] =  itr.next().toString();
                        count++;
                }

                intent.putExtra("find",data);

                if (choice_pir)
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                else
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Активити видно");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Активити получает фокус");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Активити в паузе");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Активити остановлено");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            choice_pir = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Активити уничтожено");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: зависит от конкретного устройства. Пробовали на разных?

Comment: Нет, на данный момент HTC One. Ну попробую. Версия андроид 4.4.2. Ну хотелось бы чтобы и тут нормально работало))) а вообще в идеале нужно чтобы работало на всех версиях андроид выше 19 API

Comment: Bluetooth в Android это сплошная помойка. У каждого производителя чуть ли не своя реализация. Кроме того полно разных радиомодулей, и даже сам стандарт Bluetooth не доработан. Занимаюсь этим хламом уже 2 года, и по крайней мере раз в месяц находится такой андроид-дивайс, на котором все реализовано по-новому, и не работает, как должно. На руках сейчас HTC One Mini, и он просто ужасен в плане Bluetooth.

Comment: Из личного опыта могу сказать, что более-менее по стандарту работают Самсунги флагманских моделей, Nexus-линейка, Sony тоже неплохо.

Comment: Жесть) А что вообще можно сделать чтобы хотя бы на этом устройстве работало норм ?) Просто я видел немного другую реализацию, везде что то подобное как у меня. Ну не хотелось бы все переделывать, тем более что я не так опытен, как заденешь что то так придется кучу всего переделывать. Просто сейчас работает ужасно, редко находит все устройства, бывает минуя событие ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED , сразу ACTION_FOUND и ACTION_UUID.

Comment: Пасибо большое) вообще я проверял так, только я все равно регестрировал ресивер, а сканирование уже начиналось в зависимости от того идет ли оно сейчас или нет.

Comment: Вообщем теперь вроде стабильно работает, правда когда несколько устройств тогда не всех находит) Может есть выход ?) А вообще спасибо реально за ответ!!!

Answer (score 1):

Например, вы могли не закончить сканирование в прошлый раз, и регистрируете ресивер, и начинаете сканирование, которое уже итак начато. В этом случае `ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` не будет. Если вам точно надо `ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` , то перед тем, как начинать сканирование, проверьте, не идет ли оно сейчас, и если уже идет - остановите, зарегистрируйте ресивер, и уже потом начинайте заново.

По поводу устройств, которые не находятся:

Можете попробовать сканировать промежутками, например по 3 секунды, и добавлять найденные устройства в общий список. Труднообъяснимо, но на моей практике за 2 подхода по 3 секунды вероятность найти устройство значительно больше, чем за 1 подход в 6 секунд.

Comment: А если так попробовать, когда нашел устройство, отменять сканирование и запускать его заново? И нужно ли при этом делать вот это  unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);

Comment: @ОлегМартынов, ну, попробуйте. Можно сделать и так, что ненадо unregisterReceiver

Comment: Блин я не пойму как организовать такой поиск по три секунды, это как поставить таймер и каждые три секунды отменять сканирование а потом включать? Дело в том что в таком случае не происходит событие ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED, я пробовал немного по другому правда ну похоже. И вот тут  if(!myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            registerReceiver(bReceiver, filter);
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        } может отменить сканирование  и заново начать если оно уже идет.